# Accessing Js from file from outside an EAR/WAR

Tags: javascript, war, ear

I have a requirement where a JS refernced by my web applications needs to reside on a location other than the context of the app. For eg. The deployed structure of my project looks like

```
myProj.ear/myProj.war/layout/thePageThatNeedsExternalJS.xhtml
```

this lives under `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy`.

Requirement states that `theJavascript.js` file should be present on the file system for eg. at

```
/home/amit/myJsFolder/theJavaScript.js
```

Now I tried referencing this JS using `scr="file:///home/amit/myJsFolder/theJavaScript.js"`

I also tried using "../../" path to try to point it to the right location but that does not seem to work either. I tried to see if the Js got linked by using the chrome developer tools and the js is not listed in the scripts section, but other scripts are for eg the Jquery script.

Is it even possible to link such a js inside a web app? Because I tried this on a single HTML page and it works.

Comment: If you want the browser to load the file, first you have to *serve* it. If it's outside your web server root, you have to create a servlet that serves the file. You cannot reference a local file from a web-served page.

Comment: @MaxArt, thanks a lot, I have now kept my JS on a web server and have linked it using http://myWebsite/web/theJavaScript.js.